# Javascript code works in JSFiddle but does not work in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, phonegap, jspdf

I am trying to create a button that will download the contents/HTML of a page. I have tested the following code in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nf34mj9y/2/. When clicked, the button creates a PDF that automatically saves.

But when I test the code in the browser (Chrome), the button does nothing. It can be clicked, but the clicking does not generate the PDF. Just nothing. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-eval'; script-src * 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src * data: 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src * 'unsafe-eval'; frame-src *;">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap://ready file:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-eval' *"> 
</head>
<body>
<span>None</span>
<div id="invoice">
    <span> Invoice Info </span>
    <span> 2020-07-20 </span>
    <span> $$$  </span>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-info" onclick="downloadPDF()">Download PDF</button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.5/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dom-to-image/2.6.0/dom-to-image.min.js"></script>
<script>function downloadPDF(){
   domtoimage.toPng(document.getElementById('invoice'))
       .then(function (blob) {
           var pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'pt', [$('#invoice').width(), $('#invoice').height()]);

           pdf.addImage(blob, 'PNG', 0, 0, $('#invoice').width(), $('#invoice').height());
           pdf.save("test.pdf");

           that.options.api.optionsChanged();
       });

       } </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Why does it work in JSFiddle but not in my browser? Could it be my environment?

Or maybe I've placed the scripts in the wrong places? Any and all help would be deeply appreciated.

EDIT: I have tried putting the Javascript into a separate JS file. Here's the HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-eval'; script-src * 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src * data: 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src * 'unsafe-eval'; frame-src *;">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap://ready file:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-eval' *">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.5/jspdf.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dom-to-image/2.6.0/dom-to-image.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/somescript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<span>None</span>
<div id="invoice">
    <span> Invoice Info </span>
    <span> 2020-07-20 </span>
    <span> $$$  </span>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-info" onclick="downloadPDF()">Download PDF</button>

</body>

</html>
```

And the Javascript is in a separate .js file:

```
function downloadPDF(){
   domtoimage.toPng(document.getElementById('invoice'))
       .then(function (blob) {
           var pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'pt', [$('#invoice').width(), $('#invoice').height()]);

           pdf.addImage(blob, 'PNG', 0, 0, $('#invoice').width(), $('#invoice').height());
           pdf.save("test.pdf");

           that.options.api.optionsChanged();
       });

       }
```

Still not working, unfortunately.

Here's a screenshot from the console:

[image]

Comment: You don't show `<html>` and `<body>` elements, which is technically valid, but you  also don't show a `<!doctype html>`, which would be problematic. Are they just missing from your example here?

Comment: Thanks for the response. It still doesn't work with everything added. I updated my code to include those elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for adding another answer, it is formatted beter here. Made it work for me.I just removed the two meta tags at the beginning of your head tag. Also added defer attribute to included script.

```js
function downloadPDF() {
  domtoimage.toPng(document.getElementById('invoice')).then(function(blob) {
    var pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'pt', [$('#invoice').width(), $('#invoice').height()]);
    pdf.addImage(blob, 'PNG', 0, 0, $('#invoice').width(), $('#invoice').height());
    pdf.save("test.pdf");
    that.options.api.optionsChanged();
  });
}

document.querySelector('#download-button').addEventListener('click', downloadPDF);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.5/jspdf.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dom-to-image/2.6.0/dom-to-image.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <span>None</span>
  <div id="invoice">
    <span> Invoice Info </span>
    <span> 2020-07-20 </span>
    <span> $$$  </span>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-info" id="download-button">Download PDF</button>
  <script defer type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Perfect, it worked! I guess those tags caused some problems. Thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is not working for security reasons.

From the Chrome extension CSP docs:

Inline JavaScript will not be executed. This restriction bans both inline  blocks and inline event handlers (e.g. ).

You cannot have inline scripts in your extension HTML like:

```
<script>alert("I'm an inline script!");</script>

<button onclick="alert('I am an inline script, too!')">
```

Rather, you must place your script into a separate file:

```
<script src="somescript.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm still pretty new to Javascript. Correct me if I'm wrong, but to carry this out I'd simply add the JS code (everything after "function downloadPDF") to a separate .js file, then reference the file in the header, then call the function with the button in the HTML doc the same? I tried doing that and still nothing. Am I missing something?

Comment: Take this to the seperate file:function downloadPDF(){
   domtoimage.toPng(document.getElementById('invoice'))
       .then(function (blob) {
           var pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'pt', [$('#invoice').width(), $('#invoice').height()]);

           pdf.addImage(blob, 'PNG', 0, 0, $('#invoice').width(), $('#invoice').height());
           pdf.save("test.pdf");

           that.options.api.optionsChanged();
       });

       }

Comment: Thanks again. I put that code into a separate JS file, which is being referenced in the header. I also put the other <script> references in the header as well. The rest of the code is the same. Unfortunately, it's still not working. Not sure why.

Comment: I edited the post and put the new code at the end of the original post. Maybe there's something off that I'm missing.

Comment: Can you send screenshot from the developer console? (Press f12)

Comment: I just added a screenshot of the console errors I'm getting to the original post.